# отображение фотографий товара wp e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, ecommerce

Установил плагин ecommerce, есть проблема, у меня отображается всего 1 картинка вместо 3 загруженных, куда копать я даже незнаю. Может у кого нить была схожая проблема? сайт работающий давно wp 3.8 сам плагин ecommerce самый последний.